# Visualizing raw bits of disk

Tags: security, hard-disk, command, ssd, forensics

Is there a command that allows me to "see" the raw bits of a disk? In other words, to ignore the filesystem and output the "big picture" of the literal zeros and ones as per the disk. (Ideally not requiring a TB-size temporary storage.)

What I'm actually looking for is a way to easily tell if sections of the disk contains long-repeating **simple** sequences, like all `0`s, all `1`s, all `01`s, all `0101011`s, etc, etc.

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: What level of "raw" do you mean? You won't be able to get at the actual magnetic flux stored on the disk, the best you can do (with `dd` etc., as outlined below) is to get a complete block (which is already processed). Looking for long repeating simple sequences in such a block will probably not make sense. Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Why do you need to look for repeating simple sequences?

Comment: @dirkt, As raw as forensically possible. What do you mean by "already processed"? ¶ Re "why"; to research the differences in state between new disks, amongst others.

Comment: If you want "as raw as forensically possible", you need to take out the platters in a clean room and read them directly. Modern harddisks are heavily encoded, and the contents the harddisk controller sends to the host computer will only have a passing resemblance to what is on the platter. With that, the high capacities hard disks have today wouldn't be possible. If you want to research differences in state between new disks, forget reading contents. The best you can do is ask the controller, via SMART, or via vendor specific commands (which the vendor won't tell you).

Comment: @dirkt, Do you mean that SMART uses vendor-specific commands? Surely there got to be some "industry standard" which is shared amongst different disks?

Comment: @Pacerier, Re "*Surely there got to be some*": not at present, which is why the world needs open firmware and hardware for disks.  Benevolent sounding advertising to the contrary, "SMART" is the [NSA's playground](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/02/how-omnipotent-hackers-tied-to-the-nsa-hid-for-14-years-and-were-found-at-last/).

Comment: SMART is standardized, and while it's a bit better to determine "difference in state between new disks" (like giving statistics on read errors etc.), it's still far from accessing raw information. For which you'll need vendor-specific commands, or alternatively hack the microcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sparklines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparkline) may help... first get the [`spark` util](https://github.com/holman/spark) and install the [`most` text viewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_(Unix)).

1. This hack displays an abstract view of the first *61* sectors of
   */dev/sda*:

   ```
   for f in `seq 0 1 60` ; do :
       printf "%.03i %s\n" $f \
           $({   printf '4294967295\n'
                 sudo dd if=/dev/sda skip=$f bs=512 count=1 2> /dev/null |
                 od -v -A n -t uI ; } | 
              spark | sed 's/^.//' )
   done | most
   ```

   Output on my system (abbreviated first two lines):

   ```
   000 ▁▁▁▃▆▆▁▁▄▇▂▆▁▁▆▁▁▁▄▄▄▁ ...
   001 ▁▆▃▇▂▁▁▁▄▃▆▂▄▂▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▂ ...
   ```

   Each row represents a disk sector.  Short lines are small numbers,
   tall lines are large numbers.  Each sparkline char here represents
   an unsigned integer, (4 bytes), which is relatively compact.  If it
   doesn't all fit on the screen in `most`, use the right and left
   arrows to scroll sideways.

   To see what empty data looks like replace the `/dev/sda` with
   `/dev/zero`.

   The above code can be used to skim a disk, just by changing the
   `seq` values.  Use `sudo hdparm -i /dev/sda | grep CurCHS` to get
   the cylinder (tracks), heads, and sector numbers, which on my system
   returns:

   ```
   CurCHS=16383/16/63, CurSects=16514064, LBA=yes, LBAsects=312581808
   ```

   This means every *16383rd* sector is the first sector of a (virtual)
   track.  For a mostly blank disk skimming these would show where the
   data runs out.

   Changing the `seq` above to `seq 0 16383 $((16383*60))` would show
   the first sectors of the first *61* tracks on the disk.

   To make the sparkline show just 1 byte per char, change `4294967295`
   to `255`, and `uI` to `uC`.

   ---

   Notes on how the code works:

   `dd` sends one *512 byte* sector of data to `od` which outputs
   unsigned integers, which is the largest number that `spark`
   understands.

   `spark` uses relative heights calculated from the input, (try `spark
   <<< '1 2 3 4'` to see how it works), which means unless there's a
   leading maximum number, the different lines could be to different
   scales.  To avoid misleading different scales, `printf` is used to
   prepend the correct maximum which makes `spark` use one consistent
   scale, but leaves behind an unwanted first tall char, which is later
   removed with `sed`.

   ---
2. A similar technique can show a fuzzy overview of the data density of
   a disk or partition.  Instead of abstracting a
   few *bytes* into a spark character, abstract a sampling of *blocks*,
   or rather the relative compression ratios of a sampling of blocks.

   Two more utils are required: [`pigz`](http://zlib.net/pigz/), (for mostly
   headerless *zlib* compression), and [`pv`](https://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml).  `pv` is really
   optional, but a progress bar makes the wait less tedious.

   The code:

   ```
   d=sda b=512 c=1 m=$(( (512*$(</sys/block/${d/s???*/${d%%[0-9]*}/$d}/size))/b )) \
   s=200 i=$((m/s)) ; \
   for ((f=0;f<m;f+=i)) ; do 
      sudo dd if=/dev/${d} skip=$f bs=$b count=$c 2> /dev/null | 
      pigz -9z | 
      wc -c
   done | pv -l -s $s -i "0.1" \
             -F 'Read %b of '"$((s+1)) $((b*c))-byte"' blocks %p%e' | 
   spark
   ```

   Output (on my HD):

   ```
   Read  201  of 201 512-byte blocks [=====================================>] 100%
   ▇███▁█▂██▃█▆▂▂██▃▆███▆█▅▁█████▇▂▇▂▁▇▂▂▂▆▄█▃▅█▁▄█▃▅▅▅▃▃▂▅
   ▃▂█▆▅▇▁▅▃▆▄▁█▃▇▁▁▂▂▅█████▇█████████▆█████████▅█▁████████
   ███████████████████████▆███████▆██▃███████▁████████▂███▂
   ▁▁▁▁▂▂▂▂██████████▁█▁▁▅▃▁▃█▂▅▄▅▁▁
   ```

   The hard drive `$d` is divided into 200 (`$s`) parts, and the first
   block of each part is compressed with `pigz`, piped to `wc` for a byte
   count, and the resulting list of numbers is fed to `spark`.

   The 200 `spark` characters represent the data densities of 200
   *512 byte* sample blocks.  The filled-in chars are blocks with dense data which won't compress, the shorter chars are sparse data
   which is quite compressible.

   Set `s=2000` for a more meaningful view.  The variables are all at
   the beginning, and can be tweaked as desired.  Increase `$b` (but of the form *512*2^n* only) or `$c` to read larger samples.  It's interesting that increasing the sample sizes (reading an *8K* block instead of *512 byte* one) generally draws a very similar sparkline, which implies a *512 byte* block is good enough...

Comment: Pending: a `bash` array would be a better way of associating magic numbers and strings like *255* and *uC*...

Comment: This is a nice visualization idea. Where'd you get the idea from?

Comment: "Pending" meaning?

Comment: @Pacerier, Own idea SFAIK, thanks.  *Pending* means I'll revise the answer to add array code with sensible values later.

Comment: Regarding method #2: the current code is bad for large values of `$s` -- `spark` is dog-slow if an input list has more than a few thousand numbers.

Answer (score 1):

`dd if=/dev/sda | hd | less`

That will output the entire contents of the disk in hexadecimal, one screen full at a time.  Long runs of the same *byte* sequence will be noted and skipped.

Comment: hd /dev/sda | less

Comment: @user1133275, oh yea... `hd` does take a file argument.. I'm just so used to using it as a filter... probably because normally I specify count and seek arguments to `dd` to only dump specific parts of the drive instead of the whole thing.

Comment: @psusi, Will this crash if the input is a  4TB disk? Also does it work properly for both ssd and harddisk?

Comment: @Pacerier It will not crash on lage disks, it doesn't matter if it's a HDD or SDD.